# two versions of gcc on Mac Sierra and build fails

Tags: macos, gcc

I keep failing to build a project with error
    configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

I checked and found two versions of gcc on my Mac Sierra
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc and
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
both gives version  x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0

then on default path /usr/local/bin/gcc, it is version
x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0

I suspect the default version is the wrong one which causes the build to fail, but brew upgrade gcc does not fix it. I tried brew unlink gcc, did not remove 
/usr/local/bin/gcc, and it is still the default gcc

How to remove the x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 version, and force the system to use the x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0 version?

Comment: If `brew unlink gcc` really doesn't work (it should - try it again), then try `brew uninstall gcc`.

Comment: already did. Now I get Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc

Comment: It sounds like your /usr/local is really messed up - I would be inclined to just delete the whole thing and re-install stuff from Homebrew as needed (assuming you don't have anything precious in there).

Comment: its not just /usr/local. there is a /usr/bin/gcc which is a binary, and it apparently points to /usr/local/bin/gcc. Should I erase that as well?

Comment: That's very wrong - the gcc in /usr/bin should be a symbolic link to Apple's clang - I guess someone has been messing with the default install. You might just want to re-install the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: when I try xcode-select --install, it says xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates. If I try removing or renaming /usr/bin/gcc, it says Operation not permitted.

Comment: I would just update to (or re-install) the latest Xcode, then re-install the command line tools.